# How to allocate socket buffer memory from local memory of specific NUMA node

Tags: socket, buffer

My computer has 2 CPUs, and each node has its local memory. They operate using NUMA architecture. The operating system (O/S) is Rocky Linux 9.1 (x86_64).

Additionally, each CPU is equipped with a Network Interface Card (NIC).

When opening a UDP or TCP socket for each NIC, I adjust the socket buffer size using the setsockopt() function.

Is there a way to allocate the socket buffers from the local memory of the CPU to which each NIC is associated?"

Thank you.